# What is the difference between !!variable and variable

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have seen some developers use variables in a way that does not make sense to me, and this is something I have seen more commonly in AngularJS.

Consider this code:

```
var someVariable = (someOtherVariable === 'true');
if (!!someVariable) {
     // do some stuff here
}
```

why not just leave out those two exclamation marks? Is it not the same? What is the benefit of doing it like this?

Comment: Yep, it's the same in this case. And since `someVariable` is guaranteed to be a Boolean, "casting" it to a Boolean makes even less sense. There is no benefit here at all.

Comment: `!!someVariable`  is the same that `someVariable`.  `!!` is like doble negation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The double not operator `!!` coerces a (potentially non-boolean) value to a boolean.

In your specific example:

```
var someVariable = (someOtherVariable === 'true');
if (!!someVariable) {
     // do some stuff here
}
```

`someVariable` is already guaranteed to be a Boolean (since the result of an `===` comparison is always a Boolean) so coercing it to a Boolean does not change the operation in any way and is pretty much wasted code.  Even if it wasn't already a Boolean, you don't need to coerce it to a Boolean just to test it like `if (someVariable)` either so there's yet another reason not to use the `!!` here.

When `!!` is useful is when you want to store a true Boolean somewhere, but you may only have a truthy or falsey value, not necessarily a true Boolean.  Then you can coerce it to a Boolean with the `!!`.

---

So, suppose you had some value that is not necessarily a Boolean and you wanted to set some other value to a true Boolean based on the truthy-ness or falsey-ness of the first variable.  You could do this:

```
var myVar;
if (someVar) {
    myVar = true;
} else {
    myVar = false;
}
```

or this:

```
myVar = someVar ? true : false;
```

or this:

```
myVar = !!someVar;
```

Comment: Yep. `if` statements coerce the condition value to a Boolean automatically.

Answer (score 1):

`!!` is the double not operator. It coerces the operand to a `Boolean`.

in terms of conditional statements, `if (!!someVariable) { }` is the equivalent of `if (someVariable) { }` because the condition will be met if the value is truthy since there is auto boolean coercion.

Comment: I think the OP knows that. The other part of the question is what the difference is and if there is any benefit here.

Comment: No readability benefit, thats for sure.